# Activity logger for windows?

Tags: windows, software-rec

I would like to log the activity that is done on my windows.

For example I would like to log if a user

- open an executable (which executable)
- install a software
- copy a files

And simple stuff like this.

Are there any software (freeware if possibile) that does this?

PS: I don't want a keylogger

Comment: I found it: HomeGuard. But it's not freeware but it's pretty awesome

Comment: This is Exactly what a Keylogger does (or can do)

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use [RescueTime](http://www.rescuetime.com) which comes in free as well as pro versions.

> RescueTime helps you figure out the answer by showing you how you spend your time on the computer.

Or else you can use [HomeGuard](http://veridium.net/homeguard-activity-monitor/) too.

> HomeGuard is an advanced parental control and activity monitoring tool for family and child safety online and offline. Once installed HomeGuard will silently and automatically block all pornographic and inappropriate content online and record detailed website activity including time of visit and time spent on each website.
>
> Plus a built in keylogger, activity based screenshots, chat and email monitoring and filtering, program/games blocking and time restrictions, Internet and computer usage time restrictions, email notifications and more. HomeGuard is virtually impossible to tamper with, it cannot be bypassed using proxy servers and is unclosable and uninstallable unless the administrative password (provided during installation) is used.